# Sql Server 2008 high availability in EC2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, database-mirroring

I'm currently evaluating a strategy that will enable high availability with SQL Server 2008 and redundant servers to limit DB downtime.

My thought right now is to setup SQL server 2008 mirroring in high safety mode so two machines will be perfectly in sync with each other. These two machines will be in the same EC2 Availability Zone so that the latency between them will be low.

This would provide protection for a single DB server going down, but if there are issues with this Availability Zone, the DB will still be offline.

My thought was to have another DB server in a different region entirely. My only question would be how to keep this server up to date with current DB transactions.

It's my understanding that SQL Server 2008 only supports mirroring between two machines (and potentially involving a third witness machine) so I'm not sure what the best strategy would be to keep that server up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You could use log shipping alongside mirroring to maintain the third instance

See [this article on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187016.aspx) for more about this.